# Can not see remote TV in Tizen Studio with Remote Device Manager

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-studio

I set my Samsung smart TV in develop mode and associate the IP of my PC.
Both devices are on the same network. However, when I search the TV in Tizen Studio with Remote Device Manager, I don't find it.
I tried to set the IP of my TV manually, but it failed with this:

[image: Screenshot from Tizen Studio]

Comment: What's the IP address of the TV?

Comment: 192.168.250.103

Comment: Try `sdb connect 192.168.250.103:26101` from PC shell.

Comment: ozbek your comment here saved me. i want to point out though i had to remove the port for it to work. even though i entered the correct port.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you've entered developer mode in your TV (12345 in APPS panel), then you need to enter the IP of the PC you're connecting with.

I did that and still had problems connecting, finally I noticed that since the language in my TV was a right-to-left language, **the boxes for entering the IP were in the wrong direction** (!) (which is actually the right direction right-to-left wise, but still you will never think of entering an IP right-to-left). I entered the IP opposite (103.250.168.192 in your case) and it connected. Flabbergasted.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting, that not all versions of the IDE can connect to all displays. *E.g.* Tizen 3.0 displays cannot connect to Tizen IDE Rev 2.4.

If your problem persist, make sure to get the latest Tizen Studio and try connecting with that.

Answer (score 0):

Let me write my experiences and this does not mean exact answer, just my experience.
Before I settled fixed ip address to my pc, connecting tv was working well, but whenever my pc restarted, i had to set ip address in tv because ip address changes every time.
I settled fixed ip address to my pc, and after that connecting with tv was failed.
I removed fixed ip address setting on my pc and connecting was working.
Will be glad if it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous solutions worked for me. Also the scanner was not picking up my TV either.

I noticed on the [Samsung docs for TV Device](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-device.html#undefined) the following under troubleshooting:

> On a macOS computer, the Tizen Studio freezes or hangs
> Update your Java Development Kit installation.

So I downloaded [the latest JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html) and entered the TV IP address manually in the add new device under Remote Device Manager (you can find it on your tv by going to `Menu > General > Network > Network Status > IP Settings`) and it worked!